# How to replace VSCode terminal icon with custom icon?

Tags: visual-studio-code

as I stated in the title. I want to add custom icon to icon in terminal in VSCode.

[image]

I want to upload my own icons where I show in the picture below. Also I want it to stay the same every time I open it. How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted it. Unfortunately VSCode doesn't have this feature. You should open a new issue on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode and ask this new feature.